# How can you send what's app messages programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, whatsapp

I am trying to implement a functionality similar to what Pushbullet does i.e reply to whats app messages programmatically without entering WhatsApp.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Unless whatsapp provides a SDK to do so its not possible. Not legally anyway :D

Comment: @pvn ya there's no api or sdk but still pushbullet app somehow does it, thats what I am trying to find out.

Comment: @AniketShinde Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Anybody able to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Look:
https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012
What's app doesn't have sdk, so without entering to What's App you can't.

Comment: pushbullet app does it, so there has to be a way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it without entering whatsapp contact chosser screen, whatsapp doesnt provide any api for that.

See : [WhatsApp Api Integration with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318004/whatsapp-api-integration-with-android)

But you can bypass the system app chooser by using this Intent:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: He wants "without entering WhatsApp".

Comment: This would take you to what'sapp contact picker. I was trying to send a message in whatsapp without going through this step.

Comment: @bashzip I'll check that.

Comment: @AniketShinde have u got any solution?

Comment: @Shubham nope, the requirement changed.

Answer (score 0):

Careful : it's illegal 
take a look at library : 
https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup

Comment: How do you know?